# Google Spreadsheet Script Editor MailApp.sendEmail not setting replyTo?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google Spreadsheet for customers to send in comments. When they submit a comment, it gets emailed to me. I use [the MailApp.sendEmail method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_mailapp#sendEmail). It works as expected except for the replyTo "advanced argument":

```
var myAdvancedArgs = { htmlBody: myHtmlBody, replyTo: customerEmail };
MailApp.sendEmail("me@example.com", "Comments Form", myBody, myAdvancedArgs);
```

customerEmail is set properly because I have it output correctly in the body of the message. htmlBody works as I do get the HTML version of the email displaying in my GMail account. However, when I click the reply button in GMail, the To: address is myself. It appears the `replyTo` is not being set at all. But then I look in the headers of the email message by clicking the little triangle next to my name with the tooltip "Show Details" and it does mention the correct reply-to address:

```
reply-to:    mycustomer@example.com
```

Is `MailApp.sendEmail` not setting the reply-to header correctly?

***UPDATE***: I've snipped a couple images to demonstrate what's happening. Either the `reply-to` header isn't set properly (maybe that's not how you do a reply to?) or GMail is not working properly for me.

First image, you see that there is a `reply-to` header created from my Google Spreadsheet script:
[image: Email from script with reply-to header set]

Second image, when I click the reply button in GMail, the to address is ***not*** filled in with the address in the `reply-to` header:
[image: Bad reply to address]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [reason to your (and my) problem](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=973#c5).

> What you are seeing is a Gmail bug, not an Apps Script bug. Basically,
>   if the reply-to is any email address that you have linked with your
>   address so you can send mail as that account from within gmail, then
>   reply-to is ignored. In other words, it will look broken to you, but
>   for any other users of your script it will work properly. Non-Gmail
>   users will see it work correctly in any case.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but if I needed it maybe others also need it!

**From my testing the replyTo worked only when I sent the mail not to the form Acount mail.
If your form is on *your@gmail.com* acount send it to *yourOtherMail@gmail.com***

```
var reply = e.namedValues['Email'];

MailApp.sendEmail("NotFormMail@mail.com", "subject", "message",{"replyTo" : '"'+reply+'"'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested like this :

```
function myFunction() {
    MailApp.sendEmail("serge----@gmail.com ", "test message",'empty body', {"replyTo" : "serge_test@yopmail.com"});   // replyTo son@insas
}
```

and it works as expected when I "reply" (using the reply button in gmail or in any mail client ) it shows up like this :

[image]

which is indeed the `replyTo` adress even if it is true that the sender is indeed the author of the script (which is also the expected behavior, see [documentation about scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_google_accounts?hl=fr-FR#understandingPermissions))

So I'm afraid the [issue you raised](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2440) is invalid...

Comment: ummm.. so you're saying that my issue (which others are having too apparently according to your link) is invalid because we are just imagining the reply button not working correctly? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I just tested because I was surprised by this issue... I use the "reply to" in many scripts and never had any issue with it... As I said, the author of the mail and the adress to reply to are two different things. Taking that into account, it works as expected in all my apps and in the tests I just made. If you want I've no objection to remove my last comment about the issue reference.  note : I retag your question so that it could eventually be discussed in the right tag. I never said I had any 'final' answer nor a complete and exhaustive knowledge (that was the meaning of "i'm afraid")

Comment: I've updated my description to be more clear. Either the problem is the `reply-to` header is not being set correctly or GMail is not working properly with reply-to's. I'm curious, if you click the little triangle next to "a moi" in your email above, what does the `reply-to` header look like for you?