# Google Apps Script - createDraft() cannot update name and replyTo?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I found that the `options.name` and `options.replyTo` cannot be set to the new draft, while it works properly in direct sending.

is the result normal? OR any problems in the below code?

```
function pdfToClient(recipients, cliName, docblob, draftORsent){

  var subject = 'Quotation is attched';

  var string = 'Dear '+ cliName + ', <br><br> Please find the quotation as attached. <br><br>Regards,<br>ABC Company';

  var options = {};
      options.name = 'ABC Company';
      options.replyTo = 'k@abc.com';
      options.htmlBody = string; 
      options.attachments = [docblob];
  
  if (draftORsent=='sent') {
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, string, options);
  } else if (draftORsent=='draft') {
    GmailApp.createDraft(recipients, subject, string, options);
  };  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, [createDraft(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createDraft(String,String,String,Object)) is used to **create** a new draft.

If you want to **update** an existing draft email, then you need to use [update(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#update(String,String,String,Object)).

For example, this

```
var draft = GmailApp.getDrafts()[0];
draft.update(recipient, subject, body, options)
```

will update the first draft message in the drafts folder.

- If your goal is to create a new draft message, then your code works properly.
- If you want to update an existing draft message, then you need to find the draft message and then use `update` to update it.

Comment: sorry that making the misunderstanding. 
I opened the new created draft to have a look and send out. But found the name and replyTo cannot be set into the draft.

Comment: `Name` and `replyTo` are two properties that are not visible in the email UI. You can see the name after you sent the email and the `replyTo` will be the person who gets the email upon reply. Did you send the emails to see if they are indeed changed ? @faye

Comment: Once recipient email click the reply, the email is my Gmail instead of the value of `replyTo`.  :(

Comment: @faye see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/15667340/11225291. Check if other users can see the reply to functionality.

Comment: Thanks Marios, let me try their suggestions to use another gmail account and have a try again. :D

Comment: @faye if thats an issue you might need to contact the workspace admin because they may have changed this replyTo to a standard email address.